# Fabric js, i tried to add the images I loaded into an array for later usage, but they are not being stored

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

https://jsfiddle.net/darrenz/7eLmc9un/4/

I know from the console that the "console.log("this array is empty, but it should contain the image"+array);" code is running first, but then how do I use the array if all the code runs before the image is fully loaded?

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/1434470-landscape.jpg', function(img){
img.opacity=0.3;
    img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth()/2);
    img.scaleY=0.3;
     img.hasBorders= false,
        img.hasControls= false,
        img.hasRotatingPoint= false; 
     img.selectable=false;
     canvas.add(img);

   //right here

   array.push(img);
     console.log("this is the array after loading"+array);

     //

});
//
console.log("this array is empty, but it should contain the image"+array);
//
console output:
   this array is empty, but it should contain the image

   this is the array after loading <fabric.Image: { src: "https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/1434470-landscape.jpg" }>
```

Comment: create object of fabric.Image, and push it in array, then load image using `setSrc`.https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995380/3551786

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by making a function while loading the images that pass the image object and add it to the array in the function